# Automatically re-running hook on whole repository after upgrading it

Tags: pre-commit, pre-commit.com

Let's say we have some hook for a tool like Black (formatter for Python). Let's say we upgrade the hook to a version of the tool that introduces significant changes to its behavior.

Ideally we would want to re-run the hook on **all** the files in the repository, not just the next batch of modified ones. Ideally we would detect this case automatically and perform the repo-wide run either as part of the upgrade or as part of CI validations. The rest of the time pre-commit's normal behavior (only checking modified files) is fine.

How can we best achieve the ideal scenario?

One solution that comes to mind is to wrap `pre-commit autoupdate`, but as far as I can tell, that can only run all hooks on all files. It would be nice to select only the upgraded hooks.

In CI one solution is to trigger a job when the pre-commit file gets modified, but that also has issues:

- We still don't know which hook to run.
- We will trigger for changes to config as well as hook upgrades. This may or may not be desirable.

Comment: Because this is suggesting making a very simple task, running two commands, into making a very complex system to basically achievement the same result.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `pre-commit run --all-files`

https://pre-commit.com/#pre-commit-run

No need for complicated logic here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you expand on it a bit please? Do you mean we run `--all-files` for every CI job, even those triggered by changing only a few files? If yes, won't this slow down the CI significantly for larger repos?

Comment: Yes, that's the whole point. You want to akways check every file. I don't think performances is an issue here. It would have to be a very big repo for it to really matter.